# Spread operator not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, database, sequelize.js

I have a hasMany relation between the user and posts. In the code below I am trying to add posts to the userposts field of the user model if a post does not already exists. If a post already exists I basically want to update the userposts field with all the old posts and the new posts. userposts is a JSON field that exists in the user model. posted holds the value of the userposts field that exists in the user model.

When I add a new post I can see it being added in the userposts field but when I try to add more posts, In the database I get the userposts data as follows: ["Adding posts 2", "A", "d", "d", "i", "n", "g", " ", "p", "o", "s", "t", "s"]. I need it to be something like this ["Adding posts 2", "Adding posts"]

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

```
app.post('/topic', async (req,res) =>{
  
  const availPosts = await Post.create({
    text: req.body.postText,
    UserId: req.body.UserId
  })

  const findUser = await User.findOne({
    where: {id:req.body.UserId}
  })    

  // Code runs when posts already exists
  const posted = findUser.userposts // holds the value of a user's post

  if(posted){
    const newPost = ([req.body.postText, ...posted])
    let updatedPosts = await User.update({userposts:newPost },
      { where: {id: req.body.UserId}},
      )
    }
    else {
    let updatedPosts = await User.update({userposts:req.body.postText },
      { where: {id: req.body.UserId}},
      )
  }

  res.send('working')
})
```

Comment: Seems like `const posted` is not an array but a string. So the spread operator spreads it to a array of chars

Comment: All surrounding code is irrelevant. The only thing that is relevant here, is the value of `posted`, which you have not provided. If it is *really* JSON, then that explains it. JSON is text.

Comment: A description doesn't help. I asked for an exact example. The problem is how you add the first post. Probably you are adding the first post as string instead of an array an doing something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rkXZ3m2iWSA7q2dn

Comment: Yes that's what's going on. See the userposts is null at first and then we add posts by using Post.create and then update the userposts field of user model with the posts that are added . That's what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the first post, you are setting it a single string instead of an array of strings. Thus, when you search for the user the next time, `findUser.userposts` is a string an not an array, and the spread operator does, what it's defined to do and splits the string into a char array.

Instead of using only `req.body.postText` as for the value of `userposts` on the first post, use an array containing that string as follows:

```
if(posted){
  const newPost = ([req.body.postText, ...posted])
  let updatedPosts = await User.update({userposts:newPost },
      { where: {id: req.body.UserId} }
    )
}
else {
  let updatedPosts = await User.update({userposts: [req.body.postText] }, //use array here, instead of string
      { where: {id: req.body.UserId}}
    )
}
```